# Count number of slides and inner to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, zurb-foundation, carousel

I try display number on orbit slider by foundation 6. I've already change the previous and next navigation buttons. Hot to show the slider number instead orbit bullets. I need total and current slides.

like on example [image]

```
(function () {
 function slideNumber() {
 var $slides = $('.orbit-slide');
 var $activeSlide = $slides.filter('.is-active');
 var activeNum = $slides.index($activeSlide) + 1;
 $('.slider-number').innerHTML = activeNum;
 console.log(activeNum);
}

$('[data-orbit]').on('slidechange.zf.orbit', slideNumber);
})();


  <div class="orbit" role="region" aria-label="Favorite Space   Pictures" data-orbit>
                <ul class="orbit-container">
                    <button class="orbit-previous"><span class="show-  for-sr">Previous Slide</span><li></li></button>
                    <button class="orbit-next"><span class="show-for-sr">Next Slide</span><li></li></button>
                    <li class="is-active orbit-slide">
                        <img class="orbit-image" src="../images/demo-img/screen-shot.png" alt="">
                    </li>
                    <li class="orbit-slide">
                        <img class="orbit-image" src="../images/demo-img/screen-shot.png" alt="">
                    </li>
                    <li class="orbit-slide">
                        <img class="orbit-image" src="../images/demo-img/screen-shot.png" alt="">
                    </li>
                    <li class="orbit-slide">
                        <img class="orbit-image" src="../images/demo-img/event-demo.png" alt="">
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <nav class="orbit-bullets">
                    <button class="is-active" data-slide="0"><span class="show-for-sr">First slide details.</span><span class="show-for-sr">Current Slide</span></button>
                    <button data-slide="1"><span class="show-for-sr">Second slide details.</span></button>
                    <button data-slide="2"><span class="show-for-sr">Third slide details.</span></button>
                    <button data-slide="3"><span class="show-for-       sr">Fourth slide details.</span></button>
                </nav>
                <div class="slider-number"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `.on("after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit", function(event, orbit) {
  $(".slider-number").text( orbit.slide_number + " / " + orbit.total_slides);
});` from their documentation: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/orbit.html

Answer (score 0):

```
   It's work great. 
  (function() {
        function slideNumber() {
            var totalItems = $('li.orbit-slide').length;
            var currentItem = $('li.orbit-slide.is-active').index() - 1;
            $('.slider-number').html(currentItem + '/' + totalItems);
        }
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            $('[data-orbit]').on('slidechange.zf.orbit', slideNumber);
        });
    })();
```